# Devices not discovering anymore in Alexa Smart Home Skill

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Few months ago, I had demo Smart Home skill working, in which user can link account, some types of demo devices were discovering and control on it.
Currently when I discover devices, it tells 'No new devices found'. It does not show demo/virtual devices in app also.
Earlier it was working.

Response to discovery interface is same as earlier.

Here is example request:

```
{
"directive": {
    "header": {
        "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
        "name": "Discover",
        "payloadVersion": "3",
        "messageId": "90939566-c7a7-4195-93ad-1a97834a3ab7"
    },
    "payload": {
        "scope": {
            "type": "BearerToken",
            "token": "Atza|IwEBIAjCr4kpR6T2B1cEdIfvCCxQmwwRBn28bC-pMOT0gmphXVQ1RR7cpuuuyX5Zd3nIKc77VmqeBw1FHP7m2LsOloqErzjHiliicy8pvtlJ1jvUxetVarUj8LvL_e9cT39CTqyERCJLzOKicZsW6z_679I7re1MOIOragx2T6yvrDRUUxo_O3KiflwMVZe87QZqZqURydYIZeCdi1S9SwmqCgPMKBxmsMfRq1vQIFP2RLe63C8VqlkTLvcBsWmVfSNE8SFwDpJuZI3Q2tFy2q2yOgBbLdL1oTd_EK8-mh813fsrzD1GcFixrTKrUgyAZulOmAe7jqB4-4E9eZbqbZ3Iyx1sPX0ltGc1KFjcOs2nZSVnpg"
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here is Response:

```
{
"event": {
    "header": {
        "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
        "name": "Discover.Response",
        "messageId": "3d09ff51-44a5-4a57-85a2-99de5daec683",
        "payloadVersion": "3"
    },
    "payload": {
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa",
                        "version": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa.PowerController",
                        "version": "3",
                        "properties": {
                            "supported": [
                                {
                                    "name": "powerState"
                                }
                            ],
                            "proactivelyReported": false,
                            "retrievable": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "description": "Sample Endpoint Description",
                "displayCategories": [
                    "OTHER"
                ],
                "endpointId": "sample-switch-01",
                "friendlyName": "Sample Switch",
                "manufacturerName": "Sample Manufacturer"
            },
            {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa",
                        "version": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa.BrightnessController",
                        "version": "3",
                        "properties": {
                            "supported": [
                                {
                                    "name": "brightness"
                                }
                            ],
                            "proactivelyReported": false,
                            "retrievable": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "description": "Sample Endpoint Description",
                "displayCategories": [
                    "OTHER"
                ],
                "endpointId": "sample-brightness-01",
                "friendlyName": "Sample Brightness Bulb",
                "manufacturerName": "Sample Manufacturer"
            },
            {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa",
                        "version": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa.ColorTemperatureController",
                        "version": "3",
                        "properties": {
                            "supported": [
                                {
                                    "name": "SetColorTemperature"
                                }
                            ],
                            "proactivelyReported": false,
                            "retrievable": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "description": "Sample Endpoint Description",
                "displayCategories": [
                    "OTHER"
                ],
                "endpointId": "sample-dining-room-01",
                "friendlyName": "Sample Dining Room",
                "manufacturerName": "Sample Manufacturer"
            },
            {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa",
                        "version": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa.ThermostatController",
                        "version": "3",
                        "properties": {
                            "supported": [
                                {
                                    "name": "targetSetpoint"
                                }
                            ],
                            "proactivelyReported": false,
                            "retrievable": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "description": "Sample Endpoint Description",
                "displayCategories": [
                    "OTHER"
                ],
                "endpointId": "sample-heater-01",
                "friendlyName": "Sample Heater",
                "manufacturerName": "Sample Manufacturer"
            },
            {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa",
                        "version": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "AlexaInterface",
                        "interface": "Alexa.Speaker",
                        "version": "3",
                        "properties": {
                            "supported": [
                                {
                                    "name": "SetVolume"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "SetMute"
                                }
                            ],
                            "proactivelyReported": false,
                            "retrievable": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "description": "Sample Endpoint Description",
                "displayCategories": [
                    "OTHER"
                ],
                "endpointId": "sample-speaker-01",
                "friendlyName": "Sample Speaker",
                "manufacturerName": "Sample Manufacturer"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Please help, Does it have any relation to different users, database etc?

Thank you